# Perl string matching

Tags: string, perl, substring

I am facing problems with Perl string matching/searching using both `index` as well as the `=~` operator. I need to search for the string "`RT @zaynmalik: Big cover for @cosmopolitanuk ! Boys looking slick http://example.com/FcWA80HI`" in a text file.

```
if($splitlines[1] =~ /RT @zaynmalik: Big cover for @cosmopolitanuk ! Boys looking slick http://example.com/FcWA80HI/){
     ## Do something ##
}
```

However, because '`@`' is a special character in Perl, I am getting compile errors. Could you suggest me a method to do this? I tried saving the string to a variable like `$str`, but it did not work (which is understandable).

So, this is what I am doing now,

```
$max_freq_tweet = 'RT @zaynmalik: Big cover for @cosmopolitanuk ! Boys looking slick http://example.com/FcWA80HI';
if($splitlines[1] =~ /\Q$max_freq_tweet\E/){
    print FILE5 "$splitlines2[1] \n";
}
```

But it still doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: `I am getting compile errors` -- What errors? What have you tried? If you're going to ask a question without actually showing any code or error messages, you'll only get lucky if someone actually guesses what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @loldop `Can't locate telepathy.pm in @INC`.

Comment: @TLP it is in `Perl6` only :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either escape the `@` via a backslash, or use single quotes.

```
my $search_string = 'RT @zaynmalik: Big cover for @cosmopolitanuk ! Boys looking slick http://example.com/FcWA80HI';
# or:               "RT \@zaynmalik: Big cover for \@cosmopolitanuk ! Boys looking slick http://example.com/FcWA80HI"

if (-1 != index $str, $search_string) { do something }
```

If you have a string and want to use it in a regex, you should make sure to protect the meaning via `\Q...\E`:

```
if ($str =~ /\Q$search_string\E/) { do something }
```

This `\QUOT\E` doesn't prevent array interpolation, but no character in that string will be considered special; without it the `.` in the string would match any character!

Comment: `without it ...` any special character will do it's own work :)

Comment: @amon, can you please check the edited question and let me know what is wrong in the code?

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `@` in your regexp. As in `$str =~ /RT \@.*:/`.

Edit: you also escape slashes (`/`) with a backslash (`\`). `$str =~/RT \@.*: .* http:\/\/.*/`.

Comment: Okay and what about the slashes?

Answer (score -1):

You need to escape special characters with a preceding `\` (backslash).

This is relevant not only for @, but for other characters too.

To be on the safe side, you can escape any non-letter character.

Comment: Yes i tried doing that but i am not able to escape the slashes. Actually, i am extracting that string from a file, storing it in a variable and then searching for that variable in another file full of tweets. So, even if i retort to this method, it would not solve the problem entirely.

Comment: @Jones If you're looking for an entire specific line, it might be easier to use `eq`. Or index, like amon suggested.

Comment: No, i am checking for the presence of a substring.